# Gridview Row color on Mouse Over using Javascript Stopped working

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Javascript on External file

```
var oldgridSelectedColor;
function setMouseOverColor(element)
{
    oldgridSelectedColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    element.style.backgroundColor='#C0C0C0';
    element.style.cursor='hand';
    //element.style.textDecoration='underline';
}

function setMouseOutColor(element)
{
    element.style.backgroundColor=oldgridSelectedColor;
    element.style.textDecoration='none';
}

function setMouseDownColor(element) {
    oldgridSelectedColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
    element.style.cursor = 'hand';
    //element.style.textDecoration='underline';
}

function setMouseUpColor(element) {
    element.style.backgroundColor = 'Green';
    element.style.textDecoration = 'none';
}
```

rowdatabound event in aspx

```
protected void grdTenant_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Cells[0].Style["display"] = "none";

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    { 

        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseover"] = "javascript:setMouseOverColor(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onmouseout"] =   "javascript:setMouseOutColor(this);";
        e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.grdTenant, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);   
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click the row to edit.";  
    }
```

Those are the codes I am using and it they are working perfectly fine until I have changed my gridview setting putting new jquery commands to fix the gridview header. Some js commands also stopped working after I injected the new scripts and was able to fix them by using **jquery.noConflict() code.** I declare variable with that value and everything worked well again (as mentioned by some that is how to do it when you have multiple javascript codes or libraries in one page.

However, with this one, I cant fix since there are no $ command in the javascript code. I am a bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Javascript :

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.noConflict() </script>
    function MouseEvents(objRef, evt) {
        if (evt.type == "mouseover") {
            objRef.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            objRef.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
        else {
            if (evt.type == "mouseout") objRef.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        }
    }
</script>
```

CodeBehind

```
protected void grdTenant_RowDataBound(object sender, 
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "MouseEvents(this, event)");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the JS Code can be put externally?

Comment: Yes you can. Actually Sorry,I didn't read your Entire Question ? Can you tell me do you have any jquery on the Page or any jquery script you had imported on the page.

Comment: Yes a lot. Based on my initial assessment i think the error is caused by multiple js code in a page. I was able to fix it with others using the noconflict() function but in my posted codes and to yours, it is still the same.

Comment: can show the js file you imported.This may be because of Older version try to update with latest version.

Comment: try <script type="text/javascript"> jQuery.noConflict() </script> this is trick what i had done once. If you are using jquery 1.3. or less then that then remove it